# Parse json and insert the variable into a new jquery ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to learn the basics of jquery ajax and JSON formatting

My page (call it page-1) receives a json encoded response from a php script. Using my browser network tool the preview from the php script script looks as expected and it contains an id that is always unique

```
{"id":"875"}
```

on page-1 I would like to be able to have a button that retrieves the value for the id and uses it in a **NEW** ajax request that goes to a different php script (delete_list.php)

I have been trying the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#dformclose").click(function() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel this? Your image and any information in this form will be deleted")) {
    var id = id;  /*I think the problem is here*/
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType:"json",
            url: "delete_list.php",
            data: id,
            success: function(response) {
            return false;
            }
        });
    }
         else 
      { 
    return false;
   }
});
</script>
```

the page delete-list.php starts with

```
<?php
$idc = $_POST["id"];
```

When I run #dformclose and use my browsers network analysis tool on the delete_list.php file it always gives the response

```
{"success":true,"idc":null}
```

How do I define Id here using the value from the json return

Here is my first ajax request that does not process any data:

```
 $.ajax(url, {
    type: "post",
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,

    beforeSend: function () {
      _this.submitStart();
    },

    success: function (data) {
      _this.submitDone(data);
    },

    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      _this.submitFail(textStatus || errorThrown);
    },

    complete: function () {
      _this.submitEnd();
    }
  });
},
```

Why is value always null, how can I send the value 'id' to the delete_list.php?

Comment: Try using data: JSON.stringify(id) in ajax call

Comment: data in a POST needs to be key/value pairs. You are only sending a value so in php `$_POST` is empty. Also not clear where you define `id`

Comment: @charlietfl that's all I'm asking here is How do i define id!!!

Comment: You said there is another ajax request, where is that code

Comment: Where is the javascript that gets the id?

Comment: @user3263194 still null

Comment: @charlietfl There is an initial ajax request that brings the json data to the page. The ajax request I posted is the seond one that will handle the json data. I will post the first one

Comment: You can define id as var id={"id":"875"} if you have only one id. Then try using the above comment from me.

Comment: That's what I/m asking here. How do I define id, the value is coming from json

Comment: you need to store the initial response in a scope that is accessible by second event handler, or on an element or something.

Comment: @charlietfl that makes perfect sense and I bet that is the issue here. Can you give me a brief ex on how to get started on that?

Comment: @charlietfl storing in an element would be prefereable

Comment: OK, can use jQuery data to store on an element. `$(selector).data('anyNameYouWant', firstAjaxresponse)` ...then retirve with `$(sameSelector).data('sameNameAsbefore')`

Comment: What is "_this" in your first AJAX Request, Does it have any significance with the page??

Comment: @charlietfl I'm having trouble with this one. so I placed this $(".idval").data('key',id); right after console.log(data); to populate the value attribute of <input class="idval" name="id" value=""> but not working. Can you see where I might be going wrong?

Comment: can't concatenate `this` into a string. Not sure where `'.idval'` is can try `$(this).find('.idval')`. But also if there are more thann one `'.idval'` can be a problem also. Not sure hwat `this` is either